# what's the best practises for MVC web APi pure JSON?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

As per topic, i have created two samples of MVC web api with both JSON as input and output.

sample put

```
   [HttpPut] 
   public string Put(int id, [FromBody] dynamic value)
    {
        return id.ToString() + value.name + value.time;
    }
```

sample get

```
       [HttpGet]     
       public string Get()
        {
            Portal.BusinessLogic.User.FAQHelper faqHELPER = new Portal.BusinessLogic.User.FAQHelper();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(faqHELPER.getFAQs()); ;
        }
```

However, i am not sure whether this is the correct way to do a web controller which accepts and returns json string. Can anyone guide me on how to do it the efficient and safe way ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches is pretty much a default way, is to have your parameters and return type as Model of the data you save and retrieve. In this case your controller will look like this:

```
// [HttpPut]   <-- This is not needed if method called "Put...."  
public HttpResponseMessage Put (MyDataPOCOModel model)
{
   // update your data
}

// [HttpGet]  <-- This is not needed if method called "Get...."  
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
      // Get the data, pack  HttpResponseMessage and return
      // Optionally, return can be just MyDataPOCOModel 
}

//[HttpGet]  <-- This is not neededif method called "Get...."  
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
      // Get the data, pack  HttpResponseMessage and return
      // Optionally, return can be just IEnumerable<MyDataPOCOModel> 
}
```

If your code is like the one above, by default, `web api` will automatically serialize/deserialize your Model object into and from JSON